# How to query distinct number of account numbers from table?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that gives me usage for a customer in a period of time. I want to create a subquery in the "and" statement that asks for account number.

```
where 1=1
and acct.client_co_account_id in
(   
  select client_co_account_id
  from account 
  where 1=1
  and rownum <= 50000
)
```

I want usage stats for 50,000 distinct customer accounts. However, I am actually just getting 50,000 rows but not 50,000 ACCOUNTS. This query is going to give me 96 usage for each day, for one week, for one account. So it's a lot of information. There should be 672 entries for each account out of 50,000.

It's driving me nuts! By the way, the above is just a snapshot of the query. There's a lot more, I'm just working on the subquery.

THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

you could use distinct  and mysql don't have rownum but limit

```
where  acct.client_co_account_id in
(   
  select distinct client_co_account_id
  from account 
  order by client_co_account_id limit  50000
)
```

and you don't need  where 1=1

but for this is better  use a join

```
from mytable inner join  (   
  select distinct client_co_account_id
  from account 
  order by client_co_account_id limit  50000
) t on t.client_co_account_id  = mytable.acct.client_co_account_id
```

the inner join is more efficent and permit of avoid the limitation related  to max dimension of the result of a subselect in a IN clause

Comment: Why is there an extra parenthesis : t on t.client_co_account_id  ) mytable.acct.client_co_account_id

Comment: @marmar    is typo    .... need  a =   ....  answer  updated .. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want each `client_co_account_id` to appear once, the `distinct` keyword is your friend. And if you want 50,000 results, you'll need to limit the number of results and not check the row numbers

```
select distinct client_co_account_id
from account 
where 1=1
limit 50000
```

Comment: It keeps saying that the SQL statement is not properly ended with this

Comment: This query should run on its own, then you can use it as a replacement for the `select` query you were working on. Just make sure you keep the parentheses.

Comment: For some reason it just hates the limit clause and it keep saying that sql command is not properly ended